# Update dates that reflect next year and update data for particular dates

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of events that fall on specific dates and would like to know if there is a way in Excel to update those dates to apply to next year (2016). An example would be: change `01/06/2015` (Jan 6 - which lies on a Tuesday) for next year's corresponding date which would be `01/05/2016`, Jan 5 - also a Tuesday.

My next question is it possible to grab dates and use it to update the data that belongs to it. For example, for every Monday, for the rest of the year, class starts on 8:00am for a particular class, let say Philosophy.

Is there a way to select every Monday on my Excel sheet, choose a particular class and update it?

Comment: I meant 06/01/2015, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Erm.. Tuesday is Jan 6. June 1 isn't Tuesday.

Comment: yes Jan 6 is a Tuesday. what I meant 01/06/2015 is a Tuesday but for 01/06/2016 is not a Tuesday, it is a Wednesday

Comment: @pnuts Except for Leap Year... :P

Comment: I am the -1 in the end is to get the correct day ?

Comment: As for your second question, if you have times across row 1 as column headers and dates down column A as row headers, you can filter to Monday with an autofilter.  Then make the first Monday your updated class and have all the rest of the Mondays have a formula equal to the value of that first Monday's cell.

Comment: @Chrismas007 can you please provide an example. I am a visual person, sorry the hassle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1 : Try this `=DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))`

Update :
to get the closest next year's day having the same week day :  `=DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)+IF(2*ABS(WEEKDAY(A1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1)+1‌​,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))))<=7,WEEKDAY(A1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))),‌​WEEKDAY(A1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)))-7))`

For question 2 : Add a column calculating the week day `=WEEKDAY(A1)`, then apply a filter on that column

Comment: for your answer for question one, wouldnt it just change the year and the rest of the days remain the same and not reflecting the correct day its following on (meaning rather then falling on a friday for next year, it falls on a thursday)

Comment: Ah, I see, then if you're looking for the next year's day that occures on the same week day, your formula would be : `=DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)))+WEEKDAY(A1))`

Comment: kinda confuse on how the equation works. I tried to use it but it doesn't work, keeps telling me that their is an error on the equation

Comment: About how it works, the formula calculates in a first step the difference of week days between the given date and the calculated date by adding one year to the given date (difference between Monday and Wednesday would be 2 days). Then, this difference is removed from the given date plus one year

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thank you. I have entered the formula your provided but it says I have entered the formula incorrectly

Comment: @ Nor El MalkiI got it working but it doesnt work for all the days. Ex, if I enter January 3, 2015, which lies on a saturday, base on the formula, the date is January 9,2016, which it should be January 2, 2016 which is a saturday for that year. How would I compensate for that

Comment: Ok, excluding the case when just adding one year to the given date results with the exact same week day, the result should always be surrounded with 2 candidates having the same week day > example : for the Friday 10/02/2015 adding one year results is Sunday 10/02/2016, this day is surrounded with Friday 09/30/2016 and Friday 10/08/2016. Should the formula result always be the inferior candidate? Or the more accurate one (minimum difference)?

Comment: El Malkil  I would say the one that is more accurate that surrounds the week day. Just like how you explain in the example, I have been trying to figure out a formula but no success so far. Thank you for your help

Comment: With some testing gymnastics, the working formula would be `=DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)+IF(2*ABS(WEEKDAY(A1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))))<=7,WEEKDAY(A1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))),WEEKDAY(A1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)))-7))` Let me know if the result is ok

Comment: @ Nor El Malki Question, am I suppose to add this in a excel cell? and sorry for the late response

Comment: Yes, I tested the formula for a 5 years range and it did give correct results

Comment: @ Nor El Malki The formula doesn't seem to work and I check all the parenthesis. Not sure what is wrong with the formula

Comment: @RobertoFlores could you give your mail so as I send you a xls file with the working formula

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateAdd("ww", 52, dDateIn)
```

It just adds 52 weeks.

If you want to use it in your sheets, use this

```
Public Function GetDateAdd(dDate As Date) As Date

    GetDateAdd = DateAdd("ww", 52, dDate)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, even better, use this:

```
=$A$1 + 364
```

to add 52 weeks